# Input string was not in a correct format for mindbody API in symfony2

Tags: php, xml, api, symfony, soap

I am working with mind body API integrating it with symfony2  project using wmds/MindBodyAPIBundle Bundle, i am using sandbox [-99] studio for testing all working fine on localhost but when i upload project on server. it is giving me error of

```
Server was unable to read request. --->
There is an error in XML document (2, 1144). --->
Input string was not in a correct format.
```